# Android In-App Billing Library v4+ - "This item cannot be purchased" error

Tags: java, android, billingclient

I used https://github.com/Mahadev-code/Android-inApp-Billing sample code (which is otherwise great, easy to use) in an app where the user can donate for me (technically purchase an item for $1).

But i have a problem, as if i try to purchase, i  get an "This item cannot be purchased" message. The app is published to Google Play, i created an item to purchase, but it does not work. (I have another app from 2020, which uses an older BillingClient, and it is working, the consumables are registered on Play on the same way.)

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

The relevant code parts are :

```
public BillingConnector billingConnector;


 billingConnector = new BillingConnector(this, "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjZXQIdwZV4lxYJeXUNafqECbbpL9rxJCPJYLxmzNj/d69NBz/gYAnmMrFsB70iefjTd7rffnWe4MyTF3RAHbUY8Z43J0Jx7Y6vj5kQXyvNTYTuDI5f4gj1AgRuAqk64robKCOjXdtTdvf2tbxDzNT9CF3SDepJfhqMazEnGK0Tb6mksyPIvxsXxHZNVGp8FCeHSXYSwtQLA/yLLV3ZXzcTmEjf8kLqfrsznOt9pjfLED7jpeNKIzA1z3gOnGrFnfuvAA+o/sNCDq1ERc/5KPSfshGI/D406v/Z/ZTXRUWY/yNYlNQYlenTMFZz1Oa0LTCKqujIb4jrnu3m8FxoQbAwIDAQAB")
                .setConsumableIds(consumableIds)
                .setNonConsumableIds(nonConsumableIds)
                .setSubscriptionIds(subscriptionIds)
                .autoAcknowledge()
                .autoConsume()
                .enableLogging()
                .connect();

        billingConnector.setBillingEventListener(new BillingEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProductsFetched(@NonNull List<SkuInfo> skuDetails) {
                /*Provides a list with fetched products*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onPurchasedProductsFetched(@NonNull List<PurchaseInfo> purchases) {
                /*Provides a list with fetched purchased products*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onProductsPurchased(@NonNull List<PurchaseInfo> purchases) {
                /*Callback after a product is purchased*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onPurchaseAcknowledged(@NonNull PurchaseInfo purchase) {
                /*Callback after a purchase is acknowledged*/

                /*
                 * Grant user entitlement for NON-CONSUMABLE products and SUBSCRIPTIONS here
                 *
                 * Even though onProductsPurchased is triggered when a purchase is successfully made
                 * there might be a problem along the way with the payment and the purchase won't be acknowledged
                 *
                 * Google will refund users purchases that aren't acknowledged in 3 days
                 *
                 * To ensure that all valid purchases are acknowledged the library will automatically
                 * check and acknowledge all unacknowledged products at the startup
                 * */
            }

            @Override
            public void onPurchaseConsumed(@NonNull PurchaseInfo purchase) {
                /*Callback after a purchase is consumed*/

                /*
                 * CONSUMABLE products entitlement can be granted either here or in onProductsPurchased
                 * */
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingError(@NonNull BillingConnector billingConnector, @NonNull BillingResponse response) {
                /*Callback after an error occurs*/

                switch (response.getErrorType()) {
                    case CLIENT_NOT_READY:
                        //TODO - client is not ready yet
                        break;
                    case CLIENT_DISCONNECTED:
                        //TODO - client has disconnected
                        break;
                    case SKU_NOT_EXIST:
                        //TODO - sku does not exist
                        break;
                    case CONSUME_ERROR:
                        //TODO - error during consumption
                        break;
                    case ACKNOWLEDGE_ERROR:
                        //TODO - error during acknowledgment
                        break;
                    case ACKNOWLEDGE_WARNING:
                        /*
                         * This will be triggered when a purchase can not be acknowledged because the state is PENDING
                         * A purchase can be acknowledged only when the state is PURCHASED
                         *
                         * PENDING transactions usually occur when users choose cash as their form of payment
                         *
                         * Here users can be informed that it may take a while until the purchase complete
                         * and to come back later to receive their purchase
                         * */
                        //TODO - warning during acknowledgment
                        break;
                    case FETCH_PURCHASED_PRODUCTS_ERROR:
                        //TODO - error occurred while querying purchased products
                        break;
                    case BILLING_ERROR:
                        //TODO - error occurred during initialization / querying sku details
                        break;
                    case USER_CANCELED:
                        //TODO - user pressed back or canceled a dialog
                        break;
                    case SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        //TODO - network connection is down
                        break;
                    case BILLING_UNAVAILABLE:
                        //TODO - billing API version is not supported for the type requested
                        break;
                    case ITEM_UNAVAILABLE:
                        //TODO - requested product is not available for purchase
                        break;
                    case DEVELOPER_ERROR:
                        //TODO - invalid arguments provided to the API
                        break;
                    case ERROR:
                        //TODO - fatal error during the API action
                        break;
                    case ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED:
                        //TODO - failure to purchase since item is already owned
                        break;
                    case ITEM_NOT_OWNED:
                        //TODO - failure to consume since item is not owned
                        break;
                }
            }
        });


 donate_button = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.donatebutton);
                donate_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View popupView) {
                        /*a donate gombra*/
                        billingConnector.purchase(MainActivity.this, "1d");
                       // billingConnector.purchase(MainActivity.this, "$1 donation");
                //return true;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I don't feel i have made so big mistakes in the question, sry.

Comment: No, just general advice.

Answer (score 0):

Solved... So it's not enough to install the same signed APK for testing, you have to install the app from (even the beta or alpha) Google Play channel.

So if the Billing window opens in the test APK, you're on the right way :)